# Wpf Material Design Date-Time Picker

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design, material-design-in-xaml

I used the code in the Material Design in XAML Toolkit, which is below the code.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="24" />
    <Button Margin="8 0 0 0" Content="..." Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}" 
            materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogOpenedAttached="CombinedDialogOpenedEventHandler" materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogClosingAttached="CombinedDialogClosingEventHandler">
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <Grid Margin="-1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Calendar x:Name="CombinedCalendar" Margin="-1 -4 -1 0" />
                    <materialDesign:Clock x:Name="CombinedClock" DisplayAutomation="CycleWithSeconds" Is24Hours="True" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="8" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}" CommandParameter="0" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
                        CANCEL
                    </Button>
                    <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}" CommandParameter="1" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}">
                        OK
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

But I got a lot of errors. I couldn't fix errors because I'm new to wpf.

Errors:
[image: Image of Errors]

How can I fix the errors?

**Edit**:
After The materialDesign prefix be mapped, It gives another error:

"Failed to create a 'DialogOpenedAttached' from the text 'CombinedDialogOpenedEventHandler'.' Line number '21' and line position '48'.'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `materialDesign` prefix should be mapped to the `http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes` XAML namespace:

```
xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
```

Comment: Also gives error : "Failed to create a 'DialogOpenedAttached' from the text 'CombinedDialogOpenedEventHandler'.' Line number '21' and line position '48'.'"

Comment: What if you remove `DialogOpenedAttached` and `DialogClosingAttached`? Does it compile then?

Comment: Do you have `DialogOpenedAttached` and `DialogClosingAttached` in the code behind? if you press F7, you should have two event handlers(void methods) that have these names. If you don't have them, return to where they are written in xaml(Shift+F7) and retype it. When you finish with a name, press tab, it should create it for you.